# Laravel 5 Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::tags();

Tags: php, laravel, orm, laravel-5, eloquent

I have two Models that use a many to many relationship.

```
class Tag extends Model
{
    protected  $table= 'tags';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable = [
        'name'
    ];
    public function members()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Data','data_tag','tag_id','data_id')
                               ->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

and a Data Model..

```
class Data extends Model
{
    protected  $table= 'dbaccess';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable = [
        'username','password','email','added_at','user_id'
    ];

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     */
    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag','data_tag','data_id','tag_id')
                                ->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

where the `data_tag` is linking a table.

when I call the function

```
  $mani = App\Data::find(2);
```

and then

```
$mani->tags()->attach(3);
```

I get the following error.

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::tags()
```

Can anyone help me with this ?

[dd($mani) reply this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gwxQ.jpg)

Comment: what is the result of `dd( $mani );` after  `$mani = App\Data::find(2);` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are getting a collection instead of a model

Try to get the first element of the collection with:

```
$mani = App\Data::find(2)->first();
```